# Arduino port gets stuck on

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to create a pattern that will turn one of the Arduinos ports on and off. However, after about 2 on/offs it gets stuck on and won't turn off unless I unplug the Arduino. I have tried many solutions such as trying to set the int to 0 after it sends power to the port. Here is my code for the server side and for the arduino side:

Arduino Code:

```
int Relay = 13;
//The pin that the relay is attached to
//int time;
//Creates temp variable

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    while(true) {
        //Check if data has been sent from the computer:
        if (Serial.available()) {
              int time;
          //Assign serial value to temp
          time = Serial.parseInt();
          //Output value to relay

              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
          delay(time);
          digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    out.write("10000".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
}
```

If anyone sees anything wrong or sees a solution please let me know.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm out of my element, but is it possible that the Serial buffer is building up a large integer ("10000100001000010000") because of the client delay, and when the client calls `parseInt` the delay is huge?  I'm not sure how `parseInt` is implemented...

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized I had done something wrong. In this piece of code:

```
out.write("10000".getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.flush();
Thread.sleep(1500);
```

I was expecting it to wait 10 seconds until it sent another signal, but it sent `out.write("10000".getBytes("UTF-8"));`
every 1.5 seconds, causing something to go wrong. To fix this I changed

```
Thread.sleep(1500);
```

to

```
Thread.sleep(11500);
```

Thanks :)